# Классы JS (В частности ES5)

Tags: javascript

Допустим такой код:

```js
function ClassOne() {
  this.propClassOne = 'hello1';
}

function ClassTwo() {
  ClassOne.apply(this);
  this.propClassTwo = 'hello2';
}

function ClassThree() {
  ClassTwo.apply(this);
  this.propClassThree = 'hello3';
}

ClassTwo.prototype = Object.create(ClassOne.prototype);
ClassTwo.prototype.constructor = ClassTwo;

ClassThree.prototype = Object.create(ClassTwo.prototype);
ClassThree.prototype.constructor = ClassThree;

var obj = new ClassThree();
console.log(typeof obj, obj);

var newObj = Object.create(obj);
console.log(typeof newObj, newObj);
```

1. `obj` является экземпляром какого класса в данном случае?
2. `ClassOne` является супер классом для `ClassTwo` и `ClassThree` или только для `ClassTwo`?
3. И соответственно `ClassThree` является подклассом только `ClassTwo` или и `ClassOne` в том числе?

Короче растолкуйте, как правильно называть их по отношению друг к другу.

И еще, если мы к коду выше добавим:

```
var newObj = Object.create(obj);
```

4. То `newObj` становится экземпляром `obj` ?

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: сначала дай определение: экземпляра класса.

Comment: @Grundy как это сделать? Не понял.

Comment: Нужно определиться, что ты считаешь экземпляром класса. Далее все ответы станут тривиальными. Без этого может быть куча вариантов ответов, в зависимости от того что считать экземпляром класса.

Comment: @Grundy  а что принято в js считать экземпляром класса?

Comment: Учитывая, что в ES5 не было классов - то, очевидно, ничего :)

Comment: @Grundy я и пишу 'принято считать'.

Comment: @Grundy если можешь, то дай полный ответ на мой вопрос. Думаю он вполне понятен.

Comment: Кхм, откуда вдруг в JS классы? Может, это все-таки **объекты** (объектные типы), не?

Comment: @yar85 я задавал вопрос для людей которые хорошо разбираются в js и они прекрасно поймут мой вопрос. В js нет классов как в java или c++. Классы в js основаны на использовании механизма наследования прототипов.

Comment: @Topik, это не классы в js основаны на прототипах, это _вместо_ классов используются прототипы.

Comment: @Grundy Да, вернее будет так.

Comment: @Grundy хоть это и цитата из книги. Я окончательно запутался. А что означает атрибут class объекта?

Comment: @Topik, откуда ты это взял?

Comment: @Grandy Вообще из книги, но вот https://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2

Comment: @Topik если отойти от того, что данная спецификация устарела и такого скрытого поля больше нет, то можно сказать, что используется он для того, чтобы различать различные виды объектов, в описании после таблицы 8.1 в секции [Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) указано, что значение данного поля определено для всех встроенных типов, а так же доступ к нему осуществляется только внутри `Object.prototype.toString`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92303/discussion-between-grundy-and-topik).

Answer (score -1):

1. ClassThree
2. `ClassOne` является супер классом для `ClassTwo` и `ClassThree`
3. Верно
4. `newObj` не будет являться экземпляром `obj`. У них будут общие свойства из прототипа (общий прототип).

Советую следующие источники по данной теме:

- http://learn.javascript.ru/prototype
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vs6WkNyzec
- https://habr.com/ru/post/151070